# What level of access may classes without access directive? java

Tags: java, eclipse, class

Hey i just got a fast question , About java  .

What level of access may classes without access directive?

Comment: the question is not clear...can you rephrase it?

Comment: im not really sure how to rephrase it but if you just make a class without accsess directive what lvl of acsess will it have? how much of the code will it have acsess to ?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Answer (score 1):

package level.

See below link

http://staff.science.uva.nl/~heck/JAVAcourse/ch4/ss2_2.html#friendly

Answer (score 1):

According to java docs:

> If a **class** has no modifier (the default, also known as package-private), it is visible only within its own package (packages are named groups of related classes — you will learn about them in a later lesson.)
>
> At the **member** level, you can also use the public modifier or no modifier (package-private) just as with top-level classes, and with the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

THe access level is `default` i.e. package access for classes in java

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the default access qualifier, it is package-private (which means that it is accessible only to code in the same package):

```
class X{  // package-private class

    int x;  // package-private field

    void test(){}  // package-private method

}
```

Methods in interfaces are public by default, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

```
Access Levels
Modifier    Class   Package Subclass    World
public  Y   Y   Y   Y
protected   Y   Y   Y   N
no modifier Y   Y   N   N
private Y   N   N   N
```